# Plot 3D surface from normals and points

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I have a collection of (x,y,z) points with corresponding normals and values at those points. So the data is in the form `[x y z nx ny nz c]`. I want to plot a 3D surface over these points which is perpendicular to those normals and has a color corresponding to the value. So what I want is kind of the reverse of `surfnorm`.

I've managed to plot a surface using `meshgrid`, `interp2` and `surf`, but this does not take into account the normals. I also got the idea to make the surface by plotting small squares perpendicular to the normals. I managed to do that, but don't see any way to 'fill' the space between the squares, because the points are irregularly spaced.

What is a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried to `fit` the surface?  http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html

Comment: Should the surface match the data _everywhere_ _exactly_?

Comment: Oh, and another question: is there any structure in the data? E.g. are the points on some kind of a structured mesh in (x,y)? Please add such info to the question.

Comment: And I think it also matters whether the data represents exactly one surface or could contain two or more disjoint surfaces, e.g. two separated spheres.

Comment: the accurate way is to find the intersection of each pair of normal planes, then use those straight lines to find intersection points and form irregular polygons, and finally plot those planar shapes. it could be implemented in numerical ways for example grow the normal plane from the defined points until they intersect with each other; but that depends on the distribution of the points and requires a lot of run-time memory.

Comment: @Crowley I can fit the surface on the x,y,z coordinates, but I don't know of any way to do so while taking into account the normals at those coordinates.

Comment: @tvo I'm trying to match the data everywhere exactly, yes, but if proofs impossible it's not a necessary. The points are expected to have (very) roughly the same space between them, but there's no structure (as I said in the question "the points are irregularly spaced"). I'm sorry this wasn't clear.
The data represents one surface, with only one z-value for every x,y point.

Comment: @Yvon Finding the intersections is something I am trying to avoid to do manually, because its Not Fun when the points aren't on a regularly spaced mesh. However, if someone knows a good algorithm for it, or has more info about it, I'll consider it if necessary.

Comment: @BrtH if you can solve it manually but in a generalized way, there is always possibility you can convert it into machine code.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

1) Either do a direct geometric reconstruction using polygons based on the points and normals. I think the `patch` function would be useful in this context. It allows a color to be set. Disadvantage: you will need to do a lot of manual processing and handling of exceptional cases.

2) Assume a fitting function, e.g. 2D polynomials, and use an optimization approach to match the data. You will need an objective function that takes into account the `x`, `y`, `z` data on one hand, and the normal components `nx`, `ny`, `nz` on the other hand. Disadvantage: it is unlikely to get an exact representation of the original surface, depending also on your choice of fitting function.